# How to endorse specific jars in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, saml-2.0

I am getting below exception while trying to configure SAML in my weblogic application.

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"

I know that i have to endorse xalan-2.7.0.jar and xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar to resolve this error. I did it with tomcat and it worked. But i am not sure how i can do it in weblogic. Can you please help ?